# Return from DB call using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am currently trying to return a certain value from my database call in my controller with laravel. My controller currently looks like this:

```
public function systemView(Request $request, $id){
        $rpSystemCreatedBy = DB::table('rp_systems')->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'rp_systems.user_id_creator')->select('users.name')->get();
        return $rpSystemCreatedBy;
    }
```

The return value returns:

```
[{"name":"Dan Marks"}]
```

I want to return just:

```
Dan Marks
```

However I have tried multiple different way and I keep getting an error that ["name"] is invalid.
Ive used a var dump and i get this:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#180 (1) { ["name"]=> string(9) "Dan Marks" } }
```

I am now stuck and do not know how to continue.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: If you return an array in your controller, it will be converted to json automatically. That's why you should return a string instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to get `name`:

```
$rpSystemCreatedBy[0]->name
```

It's just an example which will return `name` of the first row. To get all names in your template, use `@foreach`:

```
@foreach ($rpSystemCreatedBy as $a)
    {{ $a->name }}
@endforeach
```

Or in controller:

```
foreach ($rpSystemCreatedBy as $a){
    $theName = $a->name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much I been ripping my hair out over this and its such a simple thing.